# How to manage squid proxy

Tags: 22.04, squid

I have set up a squid proxy, which is working fine.
However I want to know how to manage the squid proxy. Monitoring things like which hosts uses the proxy the most, amount of traffic, that kind of things.
Is there a nice web page, or an easy commandline tool? Or do I have to go through the logs to see these things?